# Computational Complexity of Higher Order Functions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, complexity-theory, higher-order-functions

Map and filter seem like they would be linear O(n) because they only have to traverse a list once, but is their complexity affected by the function being passed? For example are the two examples below of the same order?

```
map (+) list

map (complex_function) list
```

Comment: a good example might be `filter isPrime [1..n]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In virtually all cases, when the documentation of an higher order function states its complexity is `O(f(n))`, this is assuming that the higher order function has constant time complexity `O(1)`. Further, the exact meaning of `n` can vary, but when not explicitly stated it should be clear from the context: e.g. the length of a list, the number of elements/associations in a set/map, and so on.

Assume we have a higher order function `g` called as `g h ...` where `h` is a function and the `...` are first order data. Without any other information about the higher-order function `g`, if the documentation states it's `O(f(n))`, you can get a more realistic worst-case bound of `O(f(n)) * CostH` where `CostH` represents the cost of calling `H` once.

Of course, `CostH` will also depend on which arguments are begin passed to `h`: here, all we know is that those arguments are being built in `O(f(n))` time. It's hard to get a useful general bound on the size of the arguments for `h` since, for instance, if `h` takes trees as input, then you can build a very large tree in a short time:

```
foo :: Int -> Tree ()
foo 0 = Tree []
foo m = Tree [t,t] where t = foo (m-1)
```

The above builds a tree having `2^m` leaves in `m` time (thanks to sharing). This can be adapted to `3^m` or to `b^m` trivially keeping `b*m` complexity.

However, there might be some way to exploit parametricity to recover a more useful bound. For instance, if our order function has type

```
g :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> Int
```

then we *know* that `g h [...]` can only call `h` with arguments taken from the list. Similarly, the library function call `sortBy h [...]` can only use `h` to compare two elements in the supplied list.

I have however no idea about how to formalize and prove the sketched claim above. It's quite possible that there are some research papers on the topic.

Comment: I'd never have thought about using parametricity to pull a time bound from thin air. I think it's of fairly limited utility though—whatever information you *do* give the function can be fed to a busy beaver or some such.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have a (common) misunderstanding that complexity is a function of `n`.

What is `n`?

`n` is just one parameter that measures something about your input. It might not be a sufficient (or even necessary) statistic for describing your input -- you might need other variables to accurately describe the complexity of your input.

So, `map` and `filter` are are linear *in `n`*. Their dependence on other variables depends on the function you pass, but their dependence on `n` generally doesn't.

(Footnote: yes, you *can* pass a function to `map` and `filter` that actually performs more work as it processes more elements, but that's uninteresting and beside the point I'm trying to make here.)

Comment: Are you sure about that footnote? I don't see how you could do such a thing, although `traverse` and `filterM` certainly can. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dfeuer: I think so? Just append every element you see to an array, and perform an extra dummy scan through the entire array before doing so.

Comment: You can only do that from a function that's been passed to map or filter if you're using `unsafePerformIO`

Answer (score 3):

For some background on complexity and higher-order functions, see, e.g.,

Hofmann, Martin. An Application of Category-Theoretic Semantics to the Characterisation of Complexity Classes Using Higher-Order Function Algebras.

Bull. Symbolic Logic 3 (1997), no. 4, 469--486. https://doi.org/10.2307/421100

Comment: It would be a good idea to summarize some of the main points (especially with regard to the question) since that's an offsite link (link-only answers are discouraged here) and it also requires a subscription to view.